# Почему при команде delete[] выходит ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
char *str3 = new char[SIZE];
str3 = "Amygdala";
delete[] str3; // Здесь ошибка
```

Пожалуйста, объясните что не так.

Comment: Потому что в [tag:c], нет таких операторов как `new`, `delete`, `delete[]`.

Comment: 1) в Си нет ни `new`, ни `delete`. 2) присваивание затирает указатель и ты пытаешься удалить константную строку, а не выделенную память. Правильным бы было сделать `strcpy(str3, "Amygdala")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что происходит?

```
char *str3 = new char[SIZE];
```

Вы выделяете память и присваиваете указатель на этот блок переменной `str3`

```
str3 = "Amygdala";
```

Вы присваиваете переменной `str3` указатель на константную строку

```
delete[] str3;
```

Вы пытаетесь удалить указатель на константную строку.

Что нужно делать? Нужно после выделения памяти **скопировать** туда необходимое содержимое. Сделать это можно функцией

```
strcpy(str3, "Amygdala")
```

или подобными.

И, кстати, сравнивать строки нужно тоже по содержимому.

```
strcpy(str3, "Amygdala");
bool test1 = str3 == "Amygdala";
bool test2 = strcmp(str3, "Amygdala") == 0;
```

`test1` будет равно false, а `test2` true